# Setting up a VPN connection before login automatically

Tags: active-directory, vpn, login, microsoft-forefront

Our company's domain controller is located in data center behind the Forefront TMG with a VPN gateway set up.

I want my Windows 7 machines to be able to work in an active directory domain environment. For that, I need to VPN into the data center's network.

How do I set up a system to make a VPN connection and then login the user?

The VPN client software is the one that comes with Windows 7. It is not a separate application, but a part of a Network and Sharing Center functionality that is pre-embedded into the OS.

Comment: Have you looked into Direct Access?  Sounds like exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using the Windows 7 VPN client**

1. Log onto the PC as a Local Administrator.
2. Create a new VPN Connection, Make sure you tick the option to Allow
   other people to use the connection.
3. Log off.
4. Select the switch user button
5. At the bottom right of the screen, there should now be a network log on button.
6. Select the VPN connection and connect.

If you have already created the VPN connection with the "Allow other people to use this connection" option selected. Log onto the PC as a local administrator and recreate the VPN Connection.

Comment: Straight to the point. Thank you. Network login icon is there indeed.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on which VPN client you use.

My own experience is with Cisco VPN clients. These give you two login fields. One is the regular windows login. The other (by default in the lower left corner of the screen) was a login field for the VPN connection. This means people needed to authenticate twice.

If your people always need access to the VPN connection and you have a larger number of clients then consider using a single gateway with a VPN connection and set that router as your default gateway.  Then add a route in the router.

The latter is probably overkill if you only have one or two clients, but if you have an office with dozens of users it will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the answer to make it clear that I need an instructions on how to set up an automatic connect for build-in windows 7 VPN client.